# equivalent in cauchy integral for matrices

Tags: analysis, matrices

I don't know why $(zI-A)^{-1} = \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{z^k}$  in 
[a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337071/cauchy-integral-formula-for-matrices)!

Answer (score 2):

We need $|z| > \|A\|$ to provide that sum $\frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{z^k}$ makes sense. Then we have sum $(zI -A)\cdot \frac{1}{z} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{z^k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{z^{k}} - \frac{A^{k+1}}{z^{k + 1}}$ where every factor is telescoping with next one so the result of sumation is $I$ (remember that $1 > \frac{\|A\|}{|z|}$).

Comment: Small nitpick: The series can sometimes also make sense for $\lvert z\rvert < \lVert A \rVert$. $\lvert z\rvert > \lVert A^k\rVert^{1/k}$ for some $k > 0$ is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks.

Comment: thanks.how can we get this summation from $(zI-A)^{-1}$

Comment: Actually I don't what kind of answer you are expecting. For now I don't know whether it comes from some bigger theorem or identity directly but maybe look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series and continue your research on your own or specify what do you exactly mean by "how can we get this summation from".