# The Cauchy Integral Formula for matrices must have $\gamma$ enclose all eigenvalues of the matrix for validity, but must it contain the origin?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/337241/815585) answer shows that the Cauchy integral formula yields the analytic power series representation of a matrix function, by uniform convergence of a matrix geometric progression:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{A^n}{z^n}$$

Provided that $|z|\gt|\lambda|,\,\forall\lambda\in\Lambda(A)$ where $\Lambda$ denotes the spectrum of the matrix. The only way I can see for a smooth closed curve $\gamma$ to enclose all eigenvalues and still satisfy $|z|\gt|\lambda|$ is if $\gamma$ is enclose the open disk about the origin $B_r(0)$, where $r=\max_{\lambda\in\Lambda(A)}|\lambda|$, as it is only then that for all $z\in\gamma$ we have $|z|\gt|\lambda|$ for all $\lambda$. However, in reading texts on the Cauchy integral formula for matrix functions, it is always stated that $\gamma$ must enclose $\Lambda(A)$, but never stated that $\gamma$ must have the property I just described.

How can it be that $\gamma$ can just enclose $\Lambda(A)$ without any further requirements? Suppose all the eigenvalues are in one quadrant of the plane - any tightly enclosing $\gamma$ would fail to have the property $\forall z\in\gamma,\,\forall\lambda\in\Lambda(A),\,|z|\gt|\lambda|$ but this property is crucial for the matrix integral formula to be justified as a reasonable extension of a function to a matrix function (due to the uniform convergence property it gives).

Comment: It's a property of analytic functions: If $f$ is analytic in $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $\gamma_i$, $i=1,2$, are two curves that can be "continuously deformed" into one another within $D$, then $$\int_{\gamma_1} f(z)\, dx = \int_{\gamma_2}f(z)\, dz.$$So in the end, you're free to take whatever shape of the curve is most convenient for you.

Comment: Wouldn't that justify doing away with the enclosing-$\Lambda$ requirement altogether, then? All you'd need would be to ensure $\forall w\in\gamma,\,w\notin\Lambda(A)$ so that the inverse actually existed, but you could do away with the enclosing property - but you *can't* do that, as another user on this site has shown to me @Jose27

Comment: No, it wouldn't justify breaking the enclosing condition, since the analytic function you're working with in the Cauchy integral formula is $f(\zeta)/(\zeta-A)$ which is only analytic for $\zeta$ in the resolvent of $A$ (in other words, your region $D$ *doesn't* contain the spectrum).